# If I've already asked a question MYSELF on another spanish language forum, is it okay to/should I ask it here as well?

Tags: discusión

I've was/am active on one or two other Spanish languages forums before this site was created, and asked a multitude of questions there. Is it okay to repeat those questions here? Is it *suggested/encouraged* that I do so? The answers there are acceptable, but I feel like we might be able to do better here for some of them. Is creating duplicate content across different sites like this advisable?

[This is one of the questions I was referring to,](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/199870/i-was-the-one-who-opened-the-door) although there are several others as well. I don't think I'm qualified to judge if it is an expert question, but it seems to meet most of the requirements of what we want on this site.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the questions fit the criteria of this site's [FAQ](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq), it should be fine to post them here.  Especially if you feel the answers you've received elsewhere were inadequte.

Also especially during private beta, it can be useful to ask such questions here, so we have opportunity to further refine the site's scope.

The only reason I can think that re-asking a question here would be discouraged is if the fact that you've asked the question elsewhere has elevated the answer to the status of general reference.  If you google for your question, does your previous post show up in the top few results?

Comment: If I google the exact sentence yes, but it would be very difficult to find if you were looking for information about the grammar it concerns.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: Private beta is the perfect time to post a question like this, and see how the community responds.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you as the author of the question own the copyright to it so you are free to ask it here too.

Unless there is something you agreed to whereby all questions become the property of the forum on which you asked.

But even in the latter case you can ask it again here without copying your original wording.